# what happens to a message when it gets to a server without reading stream in java?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, client-server

If I have a server and a client and I opened a socket between the two:

1.Is it possible that the client will have a printWriter stream, in order to write things to the socket, but the server won't have in the mean time a bufferReader?

2. If the answer of 1 is yes, if that client will send a message to the server (who currently doesn't have a reading stream), what will happend to this message until te server will create a reading stream and read the message?

thank you

Answer (score 5):

This is not at all specific to Java, but `TCP/IP`. There are buffers to keep the data received, so it's not possible that some data would be lost because one end isn't "ready" yet. This is because `TCP` will retransmit data that hasn't been acknowledged as received, guaranteeing that all the bytes that are written are received on the other (barring obvious cases).

Comment: _it's not possible that some data would be lost because one end isn't "ready"_ Presumably, the buffers can be full/overflow if the server process doesn't consume fast enough?

Comment: The other end won't send more data if the buffers are full. I recommend reading a bit about [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol). It was designed to handle a lot more situations that you can imagine.

Comment: In other words, you'll block other clients and eventually time them out?

Comment: Would you design a protocol that had such an obvious flaw? Clients have their own sockets, they don't share a single one! The link above, read it.

Comment: @Pillar Individual clients have individual buffers (with most implementations, at least).  It is totally possible to saturate buffers further upstream though: that's basically how most DDOS attacks work.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @Kayaman's answer:

consider this Compile-able simple Java implemented example:

**Server Side:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SimpleServer implements Runnable{

    int          serverPort   = 45000;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    boolean      isStopped    = false;

    public SimpleServer(int port){
        this.serverPort = port;
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot listen on this port.\n" + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }    
            while(!isStopped){
                try {
                        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SimpleServer server = new SimpleServer(45000);
        new Thread(server).start();
        System.out.println("Server is waiting to connect");
    }
}
```

**Client Side:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SimpleClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket socket = null; 
        PrintWriter out = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 45000);   
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);  
            System.out.println("output stream created");
            out.write(9);
            System.out.println("message was sent to output with no listener");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // do nothing
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

the example is an implementation of a *very* basic client server connection in which a socket is created and a stream is defined only on the client side, followed by a write to the stream that will eventually be read by the server (if at all).

therefore, to answer you questions:
1) yes, it's possible to open a one-way connection stream without a "listener"
2) edit: according to @EJP: It will be saved within the socket's buffer until it is read or the socket is closed.

Comment: (2) is not correct. It will be saved within the socket's buffer until it is read or the socket is closed. Buffer overflow has nothing to do with the lifetime of a message that is already in it. This is not 'in addition to @Kayaman's answer', it is a contradiction of it.

Comment: @ejp edited to reflect your correction of the situation